# What's the appropriate approch to develop GUI programs at embedded Linux at a reader of a gambling machine?

Tags: linux, gui, ide, qt, gnome

I was asked to develop a GUI program for a Linux-based reader of a gaming machine. The reader's storage is very limited. I need to determine the following:

Language: C / C++ / Qt / Python
Library: GNOME, ...
IDE: such as Visual Studio or ...
The function of the GUI program is to show a simple structure, buttons with text with a graphical background. Could you give me some suggestions about the development approach?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc.

Comment: But, you might get some help at https://iot.stackexchange.com/  Especially if you tell us more about the reader, and the data format (I am guessing dEX)